# Developer tools (F12) internet explorer empty console but not with firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a Web Service in C# and I tested it with the developper tools (F12) of Firefox.

I can see my executions when I walk on my site in the console of developper tools.

Here is a picture :

[image]

But with Internet Explorer, the console displays nothing.

[image]

How can I do to see executions as in firefox? It is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Firebug will show you this kind of information in the console. Most of the other browsers will show that in their "Network" panel (actually Firebug shows it there too).

For IE, once in the Network panel, you will also have to click on "Start Capturing". You should then be able to see what is happening on your page.

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx

Another option would be to install Firebug for IE (https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)